# re-use data from $q promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
//controller pour connection to API
.controller('LoginConnect', ['$scope', 'connecting',
function($scope,connecting,sendtoken){
    $scope.user = {};
    var users = $scope.user;
    $scope.connect = function (users) {
      var log = $scope.user.login;
      var pass = $scope.user.password;
      var mydata = {};
      connecting.login(log,pass).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        var montoken = result.data.token;
         sessionStorage.setItem('token',montoken);
         console.log(montoken);
      });
      var mytoken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
      sendtoken.send(mytoken).then(function(userdata){
        $scope.datab = userdata;
      });
    };
  }
])

  //factory pour aller chercher le token
.factory('connecting', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q){
      var ConnectingFactory = {};
      ConnectingFactory.login = function(log,pass){
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: "http://api.tiime-ae.fr/0.1/request/login.php",
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
           transformRequest: function(obj) {
               var str = [];
               for(var p in obj)
               str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
               return str.join("&");
           },
           data: {login: log, password: pass}
           })
       .success(function(result){
          deferred.resolve(result);
          // var promise = deferred.promise;
          // promise.then(function(result){
          // var  mydata = result["data"];
          // console.log(mydata);
          //   }
          //);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
       };
       return ConnectingFactory;

}])
    //END factory pour aller chercher le token

    //Factory pour envoyer le token
    .factory('sendtoken', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q){
          var tokenreceipt = {};
          tokenreceipt.send = function(mytoken){
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           $http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: "http://api.tiime-ae.fr/0.1/request/settings-get.php",
               headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
               data: {token : mytoken}
               })
               .success(function(userdata){
                  deferred.resolve(userdata);
                  // var promise = deferred.promise;
                  // promise.then(function(result){
                  // var  mydata = result["data"];
                  // console.log(mydata);
                  //   }
                  //);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
               };
               return tokenreceipt;
    }]);
      //END Factory pour envoyer le token


;
```

Hi, I'm new in angularJS, I'm trying to send my var "mytoken" (the result of my first factory) into my second factory but it s not working can you please help me ? I m not sure but i should chained promise no ?

Comment: and i have the following error :  Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass dependency injection to controller for "sendtoken"

Try using `app.controller('LoginConnect', ['$scope', 'connecting','sendtoken'
function($scope,connecting,sendtoken){`